# input text width cross-browser issue

Tags: html, css

I'm searching but I can't find an awnser, my input text box styles very differently depending on the browser. Please see [www.suplementospt.com](http://www.suplementospt.com)(scroll down until you see the orange box).

Internet Explorer is the worst, if the input is out of focus it kind of amplifies it.

Between Chrome and Mozilla, the width varies, In mozilla it's smaller.

How can I style it so that the width is equal between browsers and so that it doesn't enlarge the input size out of focus in IE.

Comment: the input is out of fox?

Comment: As a start you can set all paddings and margins to 0px to disable default browser specifications

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you specify the width of that `input` field in `ems`. Try using `px` instead, for instance:

```
input#news-sub-input { width: 160px; }
```